# Per instance world matrix is 0.0f/NaN

Tags: directx, instancing

I'm trying to draw some cubes with Hardware Instancing.

---

However they don't get displayed. So I debugged my code, and found the source of the problem:

In my VertexShader, the var that has the per instance world matrix has a value of:

{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, NaN, NaN, NaN }

The weirdest thing is that it outpus NaN (Not a Number). Here's how I create my instanced buffer:

```
XMMATRIX trans[4];

trans[0] = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
trans[1] = XMMatrixTranslation(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
trans[2] = XMMatrixTranslation(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
trans[3] = XMMatrixTranslation(0.5, -0.5f, 0.5);

//Store world matrices
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mIV[i].world, trans[i]);

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC instDesc;
ZeroMemory(&instDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
instDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
instDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
instDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4) * 4;
instDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

//Create instanced buffer
HR(mDevice->CreateBuffer(&instDesc, NULL, &mBoxInstB));
```

Here's how I map the instanced data to my buffer:

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapSub;
mContext->Map(mBoxInstB, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &mapSub);

VertexI* idata = reinterpret_cast<VertexI*>(mapSub.pData);

idata = mIV;

mContext->Unmap(mBoxInstB, 0);
```

Thanks for the help!
If you need some more info, write it in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

The issue seem to be that you don't copy data over, you're overwriting the idata pointer with the address of mIV:

```
idata = mIV; // this changes idata to point to mIV, not copy data
```

Should be something like:

```
for(size_t i=0; i < (sizeof(mIV) / sizeof(mIV[0])); ++i){
  idata[i] = mIV[i];
}
```

Or

```
memcpy(idata, mIV, sizeof(mIV));
```

Or some other copy function to copy the whole array.
I'm assuming mIV is an array and not a pointer, if it is a pointer you need to use

```
for(size_t i=0; i < 4; ++i){
  idata[i] = mIV[i];
}
```

Ideally replace 4 with a constant or variable to keep track of the number of instances.

Comment: Thanks for that! Now I know ;D. Any other copy function still gives the same results unfortunately.....